# SAPUI5 load image in Fiori app, image path was changed

Tags: jquery, path, sapui5, sap-fiori

i am trying to load a image in my fiori app. The image is located in `/webapp/img/greendot.jpg` like this:
[image]

But then i deploy my app to my ABAP-Repository the path changed to:

```
https://<server>:<port>/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/my_application/~CD103454ACB782CF74F8A2339BE67CE1~5/img/greendot.png
```

How can i get this path so i can load my image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var sRootPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("<package_name>");
var sImagePath = sRootPath + "/img/greendot.png";
```

seems to work, but i don't know if this is the "correct" way to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

Then you are loading it wrong, you should reference the SRC-property to your relative path: "/img/greendot.png" or try "./img/greendot.png"

```
var img = new sap.m.Image({
   src : "./img/greendot.png",
});
```

there is no need during runtime to request any backend-paths...

Comment: Your suggestion leeds to: `https://<server>:<port>/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/img/greendot.png`, any other ideas? (I am loading it from the Fiori Launchpad, so i have just the Component.js)